# How to make the vector to show random values?

Tags: c++, random, input, vector

I'm trying to learn more programming as I progress through and started learning about vectors. What I just programmed here is that, I want the vector array to display random values at the given element input. 
So if I say I input 6 elements, each element would show random values. But, my program only outputs one random value.

```
int main(){

    vector<int>sam;
    cout << "How many elements?";
    int num;
    cin >> num;

    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        sam.push_back(num);
        sam[i]=rand()%100;
    }
    cout << "The vector array is: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <num; i++){
        cout << sam[i] << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

}
```

How do I make the program show different random values of the given input? Any tip/help is really appreciated :)!

Comment: Lookup C++ random number generators.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/gzcRjy)

Comment: I'm with @0x499602D2, since you are learning, learn the proper way since the beginning and throw away the C random features. Look at [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: It works for me ,osx 10.9.4  gcc version: prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: I don't suppose you just tried: `sam.push_back(rand()%100)` in your loop rather than the needless use of *both* `push_back` and `operator[]` ? And seriously, use [**`<random>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead. Once you do, you'll *never* go back to the C-runtime prng junk. It deals with many issues such as [*modulo bias*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator) that your current method suffers from (not that big a deal for such a small range, but still...).

Comment: @Manu343726 I see, I'll look into <random> :) thanks so much for your help!
and for those it worked, ,_, what went wrong for me? I'll see and fix this after taking advises here. Thanks so much everyone!